# Crear campos dinamicos y obtener valor con react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formularios

Estoy usando create-react-app

Tengo los siguientes campos:

```
<div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row pb-4 mb-4">
    <div className="w-64 font-bold h-6 mx-2 mt-3 text-gray-800">Datos de contacto
        <div>
            <button type="button" className="mr-3 text-sm bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white py-1 px-5 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
            >+</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="border-b border-gray-200">
        <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row">
            <div className="w-full  mx-2">
                <div className="my-2 p-1 bg-white flex border border-gray-200 rounded">
                    <input
                        placeholder="Nombre del contacto"
                        name="nombre"
                        value={nombre}
                        onChange={onChange}
                        className="p-1 px-2 appearance-none outline-none w-full text-gray-800 " /> </div>
            </div>
            <div className="w-full  mx-2">
                <div className="my-2 p-1 bg-white flex border border-gray-200 rounded">
                    <input
                        placeholder="Email"
                        name="email"
                        value={email}
                        onChange={onChange}
                        className="p-1 px-2 appearance-none outline-none w-full text-gray-800 " /> </div>
            </div>
            <div className="w-full  mx-2">
                <div className="my-2 p-1 bg-white flex border border-gray-200 rounded">
                    <input
                        placeholder="Teléfono"
                        name="telefono"
                        value={telefono}
                        onChange={onChange}
                        className="p-1 px-2 appearance-none outline-none w-full text-gray-800 " /> </div>
            </div>
            <div className="w-full  mx-2">
                <div className="my-2 p-1 bg-white flex border border-gray-200 rounded">
                    <input
                        placeholder="Área o Sector"
                        name="area"
                        value={area}
                        onChange={onChange}
                        className="p-1 px-2 appearance-none outline-none w-full text-gray-800 " /> </div>
            </div>
            <div className="w-full mx-2 flex items-center justify-center">
                <button type="button"
                    className="text-sm bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700 text-white py-1 px-2 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">Eliminar</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

(Vean el signo "más"(+))

[image: Como se ve el html]

Y manejo el estado del componente con onChange para obtener los valores de los campos de esta manera:

```
// State Inicial
const [datosContacto, setdatosContacto] = useState({
    nombre: '', 
    email: '', 
    telefono: '', 
    area: ''
});

const {nombre, email, telefono, area} = datosContacto;

const onChange = (e) => {

    setdatosContacto({
        ...datosContacto,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    }
    )
}
```

Como puedo crear esos campos nuevamente (e infinitamente) al presionar el boton "+"?

Al presionar el botón "eliminar" debería tener una referencia para eliminar los campos (no solo los valores, si no los campos en sí, "el codigo html").

Y además tengo que tener una referencia al "name" de cada input para manejar el estado con setState pero no tengo idea como hacer eso dinamicamente.

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

**Ejemplo Online:** https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-paper-9qnco

**Te comparto un ejemplo que cumple con lo siguiente:**

- Se creo un **defaultState** que se encargara de guardar los valores
  que cambien relacionados a una fila de componentes
- Se creo un componente llamado **Row** el cual genera una fila que
  contiene los inputs [**nombre**, **email**, **telefono**, **area**] y el botón de
  **eliminar** relacionado a esa fila
- Se creo el método **handleOnChange** el cual se encargara de actualizar
  el estado del formulario cada vez que un **input** cambie su **estado** basado en el
  **indice** de la fila, el **nombre** y el **valor** del input.
- Se creo el método **handleOnAdd** el cual se encargara de agregar una
  nueva fila al estado cuando se presione el botón de **Agregar**
- Se creo el método **handleOnRemove** el cual se encargara de **eliminar** una fila por completo al presionar el botón **eliminar** relacionado a la misma.

Como análisis particular lo primero es que necesitas tener un estado **global** o relacionado al formulario en curso el cual pueda almacenar todos los valores de los diferentes componentes **"inputs"** pero teniendo cuenta que por cada fila tienes elementos con **el mismo nombre** por lo cual debes tratar este problema como una **tabla** en la cual tienes **filas** y **columnas** cada fila tiene un **indice** y cada **columna** tiene un **nombre** por lo cual al cambiar un elemento debes relacionarlo a la **fila** en la que se encuentra.

Espero poder ayudarte.

```
const defaultState = {
  nombre: "",
  email: "",
  telefono: "",
  area: ""
};

function Row({ onChange, onRemove, nombre, email, telefono, area }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        value={nombre}
        onChange={e => onChange("nombre", e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Nombre del contacto"
      />
      <input
        placeholder="Email"
        value={email}
        onChange={e => onChange("email", e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        placeholder="Teléfono"
        value={telefono}
        onChange={e => onChange("telefono", e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        placeholder="Área o Sector"
        value={area}
        onChange={e => onChange("area", e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={onRemove}>Eliminar</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([defaultState]);

  const handleOnChange = (index, name, value) => {
    const copyRows = [...rows];
    copyRows[index] = {
      ...copyRows[index],
      [name]: value
    };
    setRows(copyRows);
  };

  const handleOnAdd = () => {
    setRows(rows.concat(defaultState));
  };

  const handleOnRemove = index => {
    const copyRows = [...rows];
    copyRows.splice(index, 1);
    setRows(copyRows);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {rows.map((row, index) => (
        <Row
          {...row}
          onChange={(name, value) => handleOnChange(index, name, value)}
          onRemove={() => handleOnRemove(index)}
          key={index}
        />
      ))}
      <button onClick={handleOnAdd}>Agregar</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución sería utilizar una lista de "grupos de campos".

Esta sería nuestra definición de un "grupo de campos":

```js
  const defaultField = {
    nombre: "",
    email: "",
    telefono: "",
    area: "",
  };
```

En este grupo tenemos los campos:

- nombre
- email
- telefono
- area

Ahora con esta definición podemos crear una lista de grupos de campos y almacenar esta en nuestro `state`:

```js
  const [data, setData] = useState([defaultField]);
```

Después podemos utilizar el `index` de cada grupo en la lista para eliminar el grupo seleccionado por el usuario:

```js
  const onDelete = (indexToDelete) => {
    const newFields = data.filter((d, index) => index !== indexToDelete);
    setData([...newFields]);
  };
```

Luego podemos replicar la misma lógica para buscar el grupo de campos y editar su valor cuando el usuario realice alguna modificación en el formulario:

```js
  const onChange = (indexParent, event) => {
    const newData = data.map((d, index) => {
      if (index === indexParent) {
        d[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
      }

      return d;
    });

    setData([...newData]);
  };
```

Finalmente te dejo un ejemplo de la implementación de esta solución, donde traté de modificar lo menos posible el código que ya tenías implementado:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const FieldInput = ({ indexParent, placeholder, name, value, onChange }) => (
  <div className="w-full  mx-2">
    <div className="my-2 p-1 bg-white flex border border-gray-200 rounded">
      <input
        placeholder={placeholder}
        name={name}
        value={value}
        onChange={(event) => onChange(indexParent, event)}
        className="p-1 px-2 appearance-none outline-none w-full text-gray-800 "
      />
    </div>
  </div>
);

const App = () => {
  const defaultFields = {
    nombre: "",
    email: "",
    telefono: "",
    area: "",
  };

  const [data, setData] = useState([defaultFields]);

  // Utilizamos el index del grupo de campos para eliminar ese grupo de la lista
  const onDelete = (indexToDelete) => {
    const newFields = data.filter((d, index) => index !== indexToDelete);
    setData([...newFields]);
  };

  // Agregamos el nuevo grupo de campos al final de la lista
  const onAdd = () => {
    setData([...data, { ...defaultFields }]);
  };

  // Utilizamos el index del grupo de campos para buscar ese grupo
  // y editar el campo correspondiente
  const onChange = (indexParent, event) => {
    const newData = data.map((d, index) => {
      if (index === indexParent) {
        d[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
      }

      return d;
    });

    setData([...newData]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row pb-4 mb-4">
        <div className="w-64 font-bold h-6 mx-2 mt-3 text-gray-800">
          Datos de contacto
          <div>
            <button
              onClick={onAdd}
              type="button"
              className="mr-3 text-sm bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white py-1 px-5 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
            >
              +
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="border-b border-gray-200">
          <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row">
            {data.map((d, index) => {
              return (
                <div key={`field-${index}`}>
                  <FieldInput
                    indexParent={index}
                    placeholder="Nombre del contacto"
                    name="nombre"
                    value={d.nombre}
                    onChange={onChange}
                  />
                  <FieldInput
                    indexParent={index}
                    placeholder="Email"
                    name="email"
                    value={d.email}
                    onChange={onChange}
                  />
                  <FieldInput
                    indexParent={index}
                    placeholder="Teléfono"
                    name="telefono"
                    value={d.telefono}
                    onChange={onChange}
                  />
                  <FieldInput
                    indexParent={index}
                    placeholder="Área o Sector"
                    name="area"
                    value={d.area}
                    onChange={onChange}
                  />

                  <div className="w-full mx-2 flex items-center justify-center">
                    <button
                      onClick={() => onDelete(index)}
                      type="button"
                      className="text-sm bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700 text-white py-1 px-2 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                    >
                      Eliminar
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Aquí puedes revisar la documentación de los métodos `filter`, `map` y de la `spread syntax`:

- `filter`: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter
- `map`: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map
- `spread syntax`: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Sintaxis_Spread